# Angular: HttpClientModule import error (could not be resolved to an NgModule class)

Tags: angular, typescript

I was trying to build a simple app with crud on fake json server

but i can't import **HttpClientModule**

Here is error message from **VS Code** :

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:2801:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

    This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HttpClientModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

    2801 export declare class HttpClientModule {
```

Here is **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeCreateComponent } from './employee-create/employee-create.component';
import { EmployeeEditComponent } from './employee-edit/employee-edit.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EmployeeCreateComponent,
    EmployeeEditComponent,
    EmployeeListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'restTest6';
}
```

note that : I didn't use **HttpClientModule** anywhere else. I imported and did `ng serve -o` and got error. Please point out what went wrong

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I had the same problem, I just run the following command and it worked after without any error.

```
npm cache verify
```

If it does not, try manually deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the modules with `npm install`.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

On npm > 6, you can also run `npm ci`, which also deletes the `node_modules` folder and reinstall packages after.

**Edit** As other answers suggested, you may need to restart`ng serve` if the above steps do not work (but they normally do)

Comment: npm cache verify. After Manuallu deleted node_Modules. then Npm install. just close and open VScode editor. It's working.

Comment: How can I use this on StackBlitiz?

Answer (score 37):

just stop ng serve before adding new package, after adding new package restart ng serve. This will solve this issue.

Comment: (ctrl+c)  then 
(ng serve) again

Answer (score 6):

First Stop ng serve and run these commands...

```
npm cache verify
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

After the installation build & run your project using the commands

```
ng build
ng serve
```

It works for me and solve the issue...

Answer (score 2):

You can add this HttpClientModule to imports in `app.component.ts`.

```
imports: [HttpClientModule]
```

Comment: Tried all other solutions mentioned in answers above, and non worked for me. This solution worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you just need to delete the node-modules folder
then update the npm by using the command

**npm i -g npm**

Then you need to build your project for maintenance of the angular project which can be done by using the command

***ng build***

then you will be able to serve or host the project by typing the command

****ng serve****

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by using the following steps

1. stoped **ng serve** cmd
2. ran **npm cache verify** cmd
3. started **ng serve** cmd

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. So, I manually deleted `node_modules` and then `npm install`. It solved as this issue was because of the corrupt dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

In my case closed VS Code, re-opened the project and did 'ng serve'. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was making some unit tests and I have added `HttpModule` into the `app.module.ts` file in the imports section. To solve this problem I just removed the `HttpModule` import from the app module and it fixed the error.

```
// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [
    // Removed from here <--
   ...
```